# How to create login for multiple roles and users in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, jwt, axios, vue-router

i want to create login page that users with different roles (e.g customers & vendors) can use it. How can i create it?

Answer (score 1):

For that case you have to set your user role in localstorage and play around your routes logic and Please check out this article it will help you https://medium.com/@manojkumar_88220/role-based-authentication-using-vue-js-2-f54e18498019

If you again need my help I can help you just message me.